# What is the Linux kernel equivalent to the memset function?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, driver, memset

I'm writing a driver that requires me to clear all the memory allocated to zero. `memset` is a userspace function, but I would like to know if the kernel provides a macro that helps me do this.

Comment: I believe `memset` is available to kernel code in Linux.

Comment: Good question. I worried about this myself. When you first work on kernel code, you tend to get caught in the mindset that nothing is available in kernel space that was available in user space. If you try it out, you should see that it works as expected.

Comment: @anthony: Another way is to just look at the headers :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/linux-kernel/2007/9/22/272453) and people commenting here that have used it, `memset` *is* available in kernel code. Maybe you just forgot to

```
#include <string.h>
```

Comment: Agreed, I've used it before in kernel-land and it has worked fine.

Comment: Hey thanks, I just assumed that since it was a <string.h> header that it was linking to a user-space library which you can't do in the kernel. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Lol, holy crap it works, Lol. Thats weird, I wonder which header file it was included in ... maybe <linux/slab.h> or something. Thats pretty neat.

Answer (score 22):

It's true `memset()` in

```
include <string.h >
```

not supposed to appear in kernel code.And the fact is it may cost you a lot to trace down where `memset()` is included during driver development. Actually `memset()` is defined in

```
#include<linux/string.h>
```

it says:

```
#ifndef __KERNEL__
#include <string.h>
#else
/* We don't want strings.h stuff being used by user stuff by accident */
```

Hope this help you type down 'memset()' with 100% sure :)

Comment: Currently it does not compile with the simple `#include <string.h>`

Answer (score 2):

I looked it up in a Linux driver development book I have (it's German, so I will give a loose translation of what it basically says) and it gives the following description:

```
#include <asm/io.h>
void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);
```

> Fills the first `n` Bytes of the given region of memory at `s` with the constant byte value `c`. If you want to set regions of [memory mapped I/O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O) memory to a constant value, you must use the `memset_io()` function.
>
> Returns a pointer to `s`.

---

Doing some more investigation... If you look into the `<asm/io.h>` sources, you can find:

```
#include <linux/string.h> /* for memset() and memcpy() */
```

...but also the definition of the `memset_io()` function, so I guess that this should be the correct `#include`.