# How to reset the buffer(initialize to zero) in driver read function:myread(struct file *file,char __user *buf,size_t len, loff_t *fops)?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I need to make this user space buffer to zero before copying the string c into the buf How to initialize the buffer to zero.

```
static ssize_t myread(struct file *file,char __user *buf,size_t len, loff_t  *fops)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO"My read with length %d \n",len);
    len = strlen(c);

    if(copy_to_user(buf,c,len) != 0)
        return -EFAULT;
    else if (*fops > 0)
        return 0;
        else
            *fops += len;
            return len;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use memset

See the manpages for usage, it will set a constant byte to a range of consecutive buf addrs

Comment: Which header has to be included to use memset in kernel space.

Comment: @zair string.h like in user land too. (see http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.7.5/arch/arm/include/asm/string.h#L25 )

Comment: i don't have 50 rep yet, so can't comment on above question comment, but that is incorrect. Should be memset(buf,0,len)

Comment: @75inchpianist yes. it shud be 'memset(buf,0,len)'

Comment: @junix :header file is linux/slab.h and not string.h as it is for userland only throwing compilation error.

Comment: @zair Funny. Actually I'd have expected it to work. Look at my link above or at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881357/what-would-be-the-kernel-equivalent-macro-to-memset What kind of error do you get when including <string.h> ?

Comment: @Junix Yeah i too got to know from that link. since it got resolved by including slab.h I just forgot what the error when i compiled and I didn't revisited.

Comment: @zair Another funny fact is that slab.h does neither bring a declaration nor a definition for memset (see http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/slab.h ) Maybe you include through slab some other header declaring it...